# For row in read limitation python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I only want to execute this loop `rownum` times:

```
rownum = 1000
with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as out:
    with open('inputfile.csv', 'rbU') as ifile:
        out_writer = csv.writer(out)
        for row in read:
            out_writer.writerow(row)
```

Inserting something like `for i in range(0, rownum):` doesn't work, but I can't make sense of where to put it, either.  How do I say `for y in x N times`?

Comment: Edit yor script to be `with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as out, open('inputfile.csv', 'rbU') as ifile` instead of nested `with`. This is probably why you are not getting anything.

Comment: @hagubear Nested `with` statement work fine.(In Python 2.6 or earlier we can only use nested with statement as multiple contexts in one line  were [ported to Python 2.7 only](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
for row in itertools.islice(read, stop = rownum):
    out_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: <3 itertools. Note that the kwarg `stop` isn't required here-- it can be positional too.

Comment: Or just skip the Python loop completely: `out_writer.writerows(itertools.islice(read, stop = rownum))`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to import `itertools`, you can also use `enumerate` and `break`:

```
    for rowidx, row in enumerate(read):
        if rowidx == MAX_ROWS: break
        out_writer.writerow(row)
```

`itertools` is more pythonic, though.